# Can you show/hide a custom tab on a per user basis?

Tags: apex, permissions, tab

Is there a way to show/hide a tab on a per user basis? I would like to manage this with Apex, but examples of managing this from the UI would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on amatorVitae's answer, there is also the possibility of using PermissionSets that can hold tab setting just like a Profile (and use very similar UI). The difference is that while a User can only have one Profile, they can have multiple PermissionSets added. So PermissionSets can sometimes be a better way of adding functionality, essentially allowing it to be "mixed-in" per User.

This chopped down User details view shows how zero or more PermissionSets can be added in without changing the Profile:

[image: PermissionSet]

Answer (score 4):

You can choose which tabs to show/hide per **profile**.  To do this, go into any `Profile` and (if using the Enhanced UI) go to `Object Settings`.  Then in each `Object`, you can choose `Tab Settings`.

Comment: Can you add mention of PermissionSet too? They now support tab settings and can be added/removed to/from each user separately from the profile.

Comment: Keith, can you post a solution that elaborates on that?  I can't add much to the convo since I haven't used it much

Comment: OK I've added an answer to try to illustrate the difference.